# Off-canvas menu not showing in iOS browsers

Tags: jquery, css

This question is repeatedly asked on SO but none of the answers works for me so I posted this.
I cannot get the off-canvas menu to work on iPhone iOS 11 Safari and Chrome although it works on desktop and Android Chrome.

```js
$('#nav-header .nav-collapse-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('#main-nav').toggleClass('nav-collapse');
});
```

```css
#main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #07090c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
    z-index: 99;
}

#main-nav.nav-collapse {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav flex-nowrap">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">...</a></li>
         ...
      </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <button class="nav-collapse-btn">...</button>
</div>
```

**I've tried:**
Adding '*touchstart*' event to the collapse button but it doesn't work.

So I think the problem is with css *transform* and *transition*. But I've already added *-webkit-* prefixes to all those codes and I can't think of anything further. You can check out this behaviour on my [site](https://chakchin.com/).

**TL;DR**
Off-canvas menu does not work on iOS browsers and I think the problem is with css *transform* and *transition*. Help me modify the code.

**Edit:**
It is not the problem with transform. When I clicked the button the nav-links are there, I can click them. I just don't see them. Strange that it only happens on iOS Safari.

Comment: Just a few suggestions to help troubleshoot: try to remove all css to the button and its parent to see if the css is blocking the click somehow. Try adjusting the script so that the nav is toggled by clicking another element in e.g. the content section (to see if there's something blocking in the header section). Also, try adding a `console.log('button clicked')` to the event listener to see, if the click is actually going through. It seems to me, that somehow there's something blocking (lying on top of the button) in ios, which isn't behaving the same way elsewhere. Cant click the search too

Answer (score 0):

Could you try out this code? I checked the website, and since you're using a separate close button to close the menu, you wouldn't need to use `toggleClass`, instead give the css transform in jQuery itself.

```js
$('.nav-collapse-btn').click(function() {
    $('#main-nav').css({
        'transform': 'translateX(0)'
    });
});
$('.nav-close-btn').click(function() {
    $('#main-nav').css({
        'transform': 'translateX(-100%)'
    });
});
```

```css
#main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background: #07090c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <nav id="main-nav">
      <ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav flex-nowrap">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      
       <button class="nav-close-btn">Close</button>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <button class="nav-collapse-btn">Open</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @user8703143 can you try checking http://derrain.com/test.html on your ios device and let me know if it is working?